# "before I got there" or "before I get there"

Tags: tense

Excerpt from Tim Powers' 'The Anubis Gates':

> "How could I know, before I got there, whether or not the world in 2116 is a radioactive cinder?"

Context: Guy1 asked Guy2 why didn't he go to 2116 with his time machine, this is Guy2's answer.

In my opinion, it should have been "How could I know, before I get there, ...", I don't get why it is "before I got there", since sentence continues with Simple Present tense.

Comment: No, got, because he is asking about something where he had already gotten there (got there, British English). How can I know before I get there. The entire incident refers to a past event. You can have is in the final clause, that doesn't change anything.

Comment: 2116 is far away in the future; hence the entire sentence can be better changed. 'How can I know before I get there, whether or not the world in 2016 will be a radioactive cinder?' However, if one is to use 'got' itself, the other argument would be 'why not a tense-change' acc to grammar rules which then will be, "How could I know, before I got there, whether or not the world in 2116 would be a radioactive cinder?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's **got**, because he is asking about something where he had already gotten there (got there, British English). How can I know before I get there? would be used in speaking at a present time.

The entire incident refers to a past event. You can have **is** in the final clause, that doesn't change anything.

"whether or not the world in 2116 is a radioactive cinder?" that phrase was true in the past but it is also true at the time the speaker said this: "How could I know, before I got there" in the present.

**Had the world been a radioactive cinder only back then, then, the speaker would have said:**

"whether or not the world in 2116 was a radioactive cinder?"

Comment: **Get there** would be correct if the speaker was talking about the immediate future:
**How could/can I know before I get there whether she will be there to welcome me?**
**Got there** is required if the situation is hypothetical. (It's hard to know how time machines affect this.)

Comment: **get there** would be correct if the speaker is speaking in the present time or as a general proposition. How do I get there from here? [now]